# CSS: Resize background image rather than cutting off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using javascript to resize a div as the browser resizes, and to set it initially when the page loads.  (Yes, I know it needs to degrade gracefully.)  The reason I can't do it all via CSS is because there is a fixed nav bar with a constant height at the top of the screen that needs to be taken into account.  I want to resize the div (and its gradient background) to fit the browser window, but when I change the CSS height property it just cuts the image off instead of resizing it, which means the next section of the page will not transition properly.  Is there an easy fix to this?

Here's the CSS I'm using right now:

```
    #homepage_aboutstrip {
        background-image:url('home/images/gradient-about-background.png');
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:1050px;
        z-index:1;
    }
```

And using IMG tags rather than background-images would work obviously, but it isn't an option here.

Comment: Why do not use the CSS3 gradients?

Comment: It's more efficient to just use a lightweight image in this case because the gradient was very carefully tweaked.  In a perfect world I might utilize those gradients, but we've got a schedule to adhere to. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with single  line css.  try this if it works

```
background-image:url('home/images/gradient-about-background.png');
background-size: cover
```

Quality of image may be disturbed  if it expands too much

Comment: Angels are singing, my friend.  Well, sort of.  It won't work for IE8, but at least it's a step.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It works for me on IE7 as well.

```
background: url(../img/url.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
background-position: 0 40px; /* Only if you want clip out space for fixed navbar */
```